# Android : Fill Spinner From Java Code Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

How do you fill a spinner from java code programmatically?

I have a spinner in the layout like this:

```
 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/consultation_deseases"
     android:layout_width="@dimen/bigSpinnerWidth"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/bigSpinnerHeight"
     android:prompt="@string/disease_prompt" />
```

With java code I need to create the adapter and add the items.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

```
// you need to have a list of data that you want the spinner to display
List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
spinnerArray.add("item1");
spinnerArray.add("item2");

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Spinner sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
sItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

also to find out what is selected you could do something like this

```
String selected = sItems.getSelectedItem().toString();
if (selected.equals("what ever the option was")) {
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Here is an example to fully programmatically:

- init a Spinner.
- fill it with data via a String List.
- resize the Spinner and add it to my View.
- format the Spinner font (font size, colour, padding).
- clear the Spinner.
- add new values to the Spinner.
- redraw the Spinner.

I am using the following class vars:

```
Spinner varSpinner;
List<String> varSpinnerData;

float varScaleX;
float varScaleY;
```

A - Init and render the Spinner (varRoot is a pointer to my main Activity):

```
public void renderSpinner() {


    List<String> myArraySpinner = new ArrayList<String>();

    myArraySpinner.add("red");
    myArraySpinner.add("green");
    myArraySpinner.add("blue");     

    varSpinnerData = myArraySpinner;

    Spinner mySpinner = new Spinner(varRoot);               

    varSpinner = mySpinner;

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(varRoot, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myArraySpinner);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down vieww
    mySpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

B - Resize and Add the Spinner to my View:

```
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams myParamsLayout = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    myParamsLayout.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;             

    myParamsLayout.leftMargin = (int) (100 * varScaleX);
    myParamsLayout.topMargin = (int) (350 * varScaleY);             
    myParamsLayout.width = (int) (300 * varScaleX);;
    myParamsLayout.height = (int) (60 * varScaleY);;


    varLayoutECommerce_Dialogue.addView(mySpinner, myParamsLayout);
```

C - Make the Click handler and use this to set the font.

```
    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int myPosition, long myID) {

            Log.i("renderSpinner -> ", "onItemSelected: " + myPosition + "/" + myID);

            ((TextView) parentView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            ((TextView) parentView.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (int) (varScaleY * 22.0f) );
            ((TextView) parentView.getChildAt(0)).setPadding(1,1,1,1);


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });

}
```

D - Update the Spinner with new data:

```
private void updateInitSpinners(){

     String mySelected = varSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
     Log.i("TPRenderECommerce_Dialogue -> ", "updateInitSpinners -> mySelected: " + mySelected);


     varSpinnerData.clear();

     varSpinnerData.add("Hello World");
     varSpinnerData.add("Hello World 2");

     ((BaseAdapter) varSpinner.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
     varSpinner.invalidate();
     varSpinner.setSelection(1);

}
```

}

What I have not been able to solve in the updateInitSpinners, is to do varSpinner.setSelection(0); and have the custom font settings activated automatically.

UPDATE:

This "ugly" solution solves the varSpinner.setSelection(0); issue, but I am not very happy with it:

```
private void updateInitSpinners(){

    String mySelected = varSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Log.i("TPRenderECommerce_Dialogue -> ", "updateInitSpinners -> mySelected: " + mySelected);


    varSpinnerData.clear();

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(varRoot, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, varSpinnerData);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
    varSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);  


    varSpinnerData.add("Hello World");
    varSpinnerData.add("Hello World 2");

    ((BaseAdapter) varSpinner.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    varSpinner.invalidate();
    varSpinner.setSelection(0);

}
```

}

Hope this helps......