# How to fill spinner dynamically

Tags: android, android-spinner, dynamic-data

I have 2 spinners on my Activity. When I have nothing selected on first spinner, second spinner is disabled. Next. When I select some item on first spinner, i want to fill second spinner any items. And every time contain data on second spinner will be change. So, how I can do this? How I can change data on my second spinner dynamically?
At this moment I try to do next:
if I have selected any item om my first spinner, I do:

```
if(dataFromFirstSp.equals("Item 1")){
    adapter2.clear();
    adapter2.addAll(Some strings);
    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
List<String> SpinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
SpinnerArray.add("what ever it is you want");
SpinnerArray.add("what ever it is you want");

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SpinnerArray);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Spinner Items = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
Items.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And to know what is clicked use this:

```
String selected = items.getSelectedItem().toString();
if (selected == "what ever the option was") {
}
```

Got it here [Android : Fill Spinner From Java Code Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920754/android-fill-spinner-from-java-code-programmatically)