# How to set Maximum size of the spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

my question is how can i set a **maximum size of a spinner**.i checked solution but they were with xml file.But i want to set spinner size manually by **java-code**. Can any one help??

Comment: follow this url it would be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920754/android-fill-spinner-from-java-code-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Cant exactly remember but you can use one of the following methods: `public void setDropDownWidth (int pixels)` ,`public void setMinimumHeight (int minHeight)` ,`public void setMinimumHeight (int minHeight)` .Use them with your spinner like: `sp.setDropDownWidth(your pixel value)`.

Also you can implement your own spinner like [this](https://github.com/ankitthakkar/DropDownSpinner).

Also you can copy the Spinner class and modify it.The [Spinner Class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2888524e03896831f487e5dee63f18f1c33c0115/core/java/android/widget/Spinner.java) is here.

Answer (score 0):

After API level 16 you can use,

```
spinner.setDropDownWidth(desiredWidth);
```