# refresh SQLite database table according to Android spinner

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-spinner

I already did my code based on [WIllJBD's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542474/android-spinner-loads-multicolumn-joined-sqlite-database-into-a-table)

I want the table refresh the data when its clicked according to spinner, but my toast gave "Database Error". Here is the code for the selected item on spinner

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        String tam = spDealer.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String dealerID = in.getDealID(tam);
        String queryrow = in.MatchDealerID(dealerID);

        if (queryrow == dealerID)
        {
            Cursor c = in.getViewInfoBilling(queryrow);
            int rows = c.getCount();
            int cols = c.getColumnCount();
            c.moveToFirst();

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                  TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                  row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));        
                  // inner for loop
                  for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
                  {
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tv.setText(c.getString(j));
                    row.addView(tv);
                  }
                  c.moveToNext();
                  mytable.addView(row);
              }
        in.close();
        } else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Billing.this, "Data Error!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

And here is my method:

```
public Cursor getViewInfoBilling(String id){
    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT BillDate,SODashboardNo, SODashboardAmount " +
    "FROM SODashboard, Bill WHERE SODashboard.SODashboardNo = Bill.TampSODashboardNo " +
    "AND SODashboard.DealerID = id", null);
    return mcursor;}

public String getDealID(String dealName) throws SQLException{
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(Dealer_TABLE, null, ""+Col_DealerName+"=?", new String[]{dealName}, null, null,null);
    if(mCursor.getCount()<1){
    mCursor.close();
    return "Not Exist";
    }
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    String tampDealID = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Col_DealerID));
    mCursor.close();
    return tampDealID;}

public String MatchDealerID(String tam){
        String matchquery = "SELECT DealerID FROM SODashboard, Dealer " +
                "WHERE SODashboard.TampDealerIDSOD = tam";
        return matchquery;
    }
```

Isnt the ID selected on spinner already same with the ID thats on DB? I already created MatchDealerID and getDealID to compare them.. what should I do make the table refreshes after clicked? Please help me to solve this issue... thank you

Comment: Read how to compare strings in java. "If (queryrow == dealerID)"??

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong in this method.

```
public Cursor getViewInfoBilling(String id){
Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT BillDate,SODashboardNo, SODashboardAmount " +
"FROM SODashboard, Bill WHERE SODashboard.SODashboardNo = Bill.TampSODashboardNo " +
"AND SODashboard.DealerID =" + id, null);

//OR
/*
Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT BillDate,SODashboardNo, SODashboardAmount " +
"FROM SODashboard, Bill WHERE SODashboard.SODashboardNo = Bill.TampSODashboardNo " +
"AND SODashboard.DealerID =?", new String[] { id });    
*/
return mcursor;}
```

There are two versions , try both , have good luck