# Add dropdownlist spinner to alert dialogue Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I'm trying to add a search form with a edittext and dropdownlist spinner to alert dialogue. I have managed to get the edit text to display, but I cannot figure out how to add the spinner. I'm new to android so any help would be appreciated.

```
private void LoadSearchDialogue()
    {
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogSearchForm = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogSearchForm.setTitle("Search Form");
        alertDialogSearchForm.setMessage("Please complete form");
        final EditText textViewInputUsername = new EditText(this);
        final Spinner spinnerSearchOptions = new Spinner(this);

        Spinner dropdownSearchOptions = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerSearchOptions);
        String[] items = new String[]{"Customer", "Employee","Date" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        dropdownSearchOptions.setAdapter(adapter);

        mQuery              = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.query);
        mSearchOption       = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSearchOptions);




        alertDialogSearchForm.setView(textViewInputUsername);
        alertDialogSearchForm.setPositiveButton("Continue",

                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Do nothing here, overriding alert dialogue button
                    }
                });
        final android.app.AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogSearchForm.create();
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getButton(android.app.AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Boolean closeAlertDialogueOnValidInput = false;
                //Check if query is entered,
                String mQueryString = textViewInputUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                if(mQueryString.length()<=0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Please enter query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    String q            = mQueryString.toString();
                    String o            = mSearchOption.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    SearchResults(q, o);
                }

                if(closeAlertDialogueOnValidInput)
                    dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });



    }
```

Comment: You need some viewgroup... Like linearlayout...

Comment: you need  searchView

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code

```
public class WvActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tx;
    String[] s = { "India ", "Arica", "India ", "Arica", "India ", "Arica",
            "India ", "Arica", "India ", "Arica" };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(WvActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s);

        tx= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        final Spinner sp = new Spinner(WvActivity.this);
        sp.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        sp.setAdapter(adp);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WvActivity.this);
        builder.setView(sp);
        builder.create().show();
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a simple xml layout for your dialog:

```
<!-- alert.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

After that you inflate a `View` from this layout file, set this view in `setView` method, fill the `Spinner` with data and do all the stuff that you need to do. All the things that you currently do to define behavior for button clicks will remain the same; but the listeners for your `EditText` and `Spinner`, if needed, will be set outside the `Dialog` (with `findViewById` and `setOnClickListener`).

To inflate a `View` from xml you need to get `LayoutInflater` and use it to create a `View`:

```
View alertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert, null);
```

To populate the `Spinner` with data, you should use an `Adapter`. There is some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920754/android-fill-spinner-from-java-code-programmatically):

```
// you need to have a list of data that you want the spinner to display
List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
spinnerArray.add("item1");
spinnerArray.add("item2");

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Spinner sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
sItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If you would like to stick to your way of creation of the `View`, you need to add not only your `EditText` to your `AlertDialog`, but a `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout` for example), that will contain both `EditText` and `Spinner`.

Comment: Hi Orlangure i tried that earlier, but the spinner was not getting populated with the data, so tried the way above

Comment: Anyway you are going to need to populate your `Spinner`, so you should try until you succeed. I added some code to demonstrate a simple way to add data to your `Spinner`. Don't forget that you need to call `findViewById` method on your `alertView` that you created with an `Inflater`.