# populate province and city in two spinner using json

Tags: android, json, spinner, dropdown

I have two spinner that the first one contains province name and the second one spinner depends on first spinner value that contains city name. I'm using json for this app and readed some article and toturial but I can't do it right 
this is my json link : [Link](http://services.alopackage.com/mobile/province)

any guide will be helpfull

thanks in advance

Comment: share you code please

Comment: This json is super bad formed, it's difficult to parse with this distribution.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS then what type of json we need to do this? could you please give me an example?

Comment: @alireza hold on, I'm creating a repository for you, I'm doing it... it takes a little bit long as I expected. I'll let you know

Comment: @alireza don't do changes on your json please.... I'm doing it

Comment: @alireza will you change your json? I can give you an option

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS ok I'll wait for it,thanks bro

Comment: @alireza Can you put it back like the first time?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS hold on please

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS now it's like the first time

Comment: @alireza No it is not, it was different man

Comment: province_id was inside of all of the provinceId objects

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I think now it's done.

Comment: I'm sorry it's not the same... and my app is not compiling now :S

Comment: You have to remove this "province_id": "1",

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android : Fill Spinner From Java Code Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920754/android-fill-spinner-from-java-code-programmatically)

Comment: If you are gonna change the json I can not help you, once you finish touching it, let me know and I'll try to help you, otherwise it's impossible, I asked you to put like the first time, if you want to do this I can finish the project, otherwise I can't.

Comment: Put your json like this : {
    "آذربایجان‌ شرقی": {
  "province_id": "1",
  "cities": [{
   "city_id": "1",
   "city_name": "آذرشهر",
   "province": "1"
  }]
 },
 "اردبيل": {
  "province_id": "2",
  "cities": [{
   "city_id": "2",
   "city_name": "اسكو",
   "province": "2"
  }]
 }



}

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS in fact I'm not touching json i just told back end programmer to make it like first time. now we are not going to change json response . I'm working on it

Comment: Ok, it's not like the first time because you didn't have the "province_id": "2" below the province_name... let me know

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS please check json

Comment: I'll put an answer now, I'm uploading on github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now with the new `json` the final code should be something like this :

You have a `City` class

```
public class City {
    private String city_id;
    private String city_name;
    private String province;
    //Setters and Getters
```

Then with this `City` class you can create the `JSONResponse` class

```
public class ResponseJSON {
    private String province_name;
    private String province_id;
    private List<City> city = null;
    //Setters and Getters
```

This is how you call your API and add the info to the `Spinner`s

```
apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Map<String, ResponseJSON>> call = apiService.getProvinceAndCity();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Map<String, ResponseJSON>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Map<String, ResponseJSON>>call, Response<Map<String, ResponseJSON>> response) {
                responseJson  = response.body();
                for(Map.Entry<String, ResponseJSON> e : responseJson.entrySet())
                {
                    provincesList.add(e.getKey());
                    for(City c : e.getValue().getCity()){
                        citiesList.add(c.getCityName());
                    }
                }
                createAdapter();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Map<String, ResponseJSON>>call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

And then you have to detect the `OnItemSelectedListener` event, so you can create a method to do this and update the city list according to your province

```
private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener provinceListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            citiesList.clear();
            String provinceSelected = spinner_province.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            for(Map.Entry<String, ResponseJSON> e : responseJson.entrySet())
            {
                if(e.getKey().equals(provinceSelected)){
                    for(City c : e.getValue().getCity()){
                        citiesList.add(c.getCityName());
                    }
                }
            }
            cityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    };
```

Hope it helps to you, I'll put the [`ProvinceAndCity2SpinnerFromJson project`](https://github.com/joancolmenerodev/ProvinceAndCity2SpinnerFromJson) there so you can understand it better.

Comment: how to get seleted city's id?

Comment: @alireza create another question this is other problem and link it to me and I'll try to figure it out :)

Comment: I have mentioned you under the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716627/how-to-get-spinners-selected-items-id-that-comes-from-json?noredirect=1#comment92359714_52716627