# How to get spinners selected item's id that comes from JSON

Tags: android, spinner

I have two spinners that second spinner's value depend on the first spinner. every item in spinner has an id that came from `JSON`. Now, I want to get second spinner's item id. I get selected item's name but I need name and id of the selected item.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Map<String, ResponseJSON2>>()
{
        @Override
        public void onResponse
                (Call<Map<String, ResponseJSON2>> call, retrofit2.Response<Map<String, ResponseJSON2>> response) {
            responseJson = response.body();
            if (responseJson != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, ResponseJSON2> e : responseJson.entrySet()) {
                    provincesList.add(e.getKey());
                    for (Model c : e.getValue().getModel()) {
                        citiesList.add(c.getName());
                   }
               }
           }
          createAdapter();
      }
}
```

Thanks.

Model.java

```
public class Model {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String taxonomy;
    private String description;
    private String images;
    private String parent;
    //getter and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "model{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", taxonomy='" + taxonomy + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", images='" + images + '\'' +
                ", parent='" + parent + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: citieslist is of type string?

Comment: @UmangBurman no , private ArrayList<String> citiesList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: You need array list of int which stores the ids too.

Comment: I think it must be hashmap<> @UmangBurman

Comment: for(Model c : e.getValue().getModel()   can u add your Model in question

Comment: @BhuvaneshwaranVellingiri I added Model

Comment: yeah create a hashmap for ids. and then you can get the id

Comment: hashmap<key(id),value(cities)>

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS bro can you help me?

Comment: @alireza check my  answer :)

Comment: So what you want now? With the second spinner get the id of what?

Comment: Did you change the code? If you did so, send me your actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a `Listener` for cities too:

```
spinner_city.setOnItemSelectedListener(citiesListener);
```

Then with this code you are able to get the `cityId`

```
private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener citiesListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String citySelected = spinner_city.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            String provinceSelected = spinner_province.getSelectedItem().toString();
            for(Map.Entry<String, ResponseJSON> e : responseJson.entrySet())
            {
                if(e.getKey().equals(provinceSelected)){
                    for(City c : e.getValue().getCity()){
                        if(citySelected.equals(c.getCityName())){
                            tv_city_id.setText(String.format("City id for %s is %s", citySelected, c.getCityId()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    };
```

Comment: thanks it's works,but I have problem with the item in zero position of city spinner.when city spinner have only one item the value of textview not changed.I tried this code ** spinner_city.setSelection(0); ** but not changed.

Comment: Whats the problem now??

Comment: for some province there is only one city and when I select those provices I can' get citiy's id in fact I think ** spinner_city.setOnItemSelectedListener(citiesListener);** not called for position ==0 , I guess the only way is adding a string as default item for spinner could solve it

Comment: Ya.. you have to select it manually,try it select it even if it's the only one

Comment: You can get the id though, but you are not able to show it on the screen, so you can do something with ID, what you want to do with that ID?

Comment: I added "select one" to province arrayList and city arrayList now "select one" is in position zero and using **spinner_city.setSelection(0);** solved my problem *** thanks for your help***

Answer (score 0):

can replace activity full code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ApiInterface apiService;
        private Spinner spinner_province;
        private Spinner spinner_city;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> provinceAdapter;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> cityAdapter;
        private ArrayList<String> provincesList = new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<String> citiesList = new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<String> citiesIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        private Map<String, ResponseJSON> responseJson;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            initUI();

            apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

            Call<Map<String, ResponseJSON>> call = apiService.getProvinceAndCity();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Map<String, ResponseJSON>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Map<String, ResponseJSON>> call, Response<Map<String, ResponseJSON>> response) {
                    responseJson = response.body();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, ResponseJSON> e : responseJson.entrySet()) {
                        provincesList.add(e.getKey());

                        for (City c : e.getValue().getCity()) {
                            citiesList.add(c.getCityName());
                        }
                    }
                    createAdapter();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Map<String, ResponseJSON>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }

        private void initUI() {
            spinner_city = findViewById(R.id.spinner_cities);
            spinner_province = findViewById(R.id.spinner_provinces);
        }

        private void createAdapter() {

            provinceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, provincesList);

            provinceAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner_province.setAdapter(provinceAdapter);
            cityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, citiesList);

            cityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner_city.setAdapter(cityAdapter);

            spinner_province.setOnItemSelectedListener(provinceListener);

            spinner_city.setOnItemSelectedListener(citiesListener);


        }

        private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener provinceListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                citiesList.clear();
                citiesIdList.clear();
                String provinceSelected = spinner_province.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                for (Map.Entry<String, ResponseJSON> e : responseJson.entrySet()) {
                    if (e.getKey().equals(provinceSelected)) {
                        for (City c : e.getValue().getCity()) {
                            citiesList.add(c.getCityName());
                            citiesIdList.add(c.getCityId());


                        }
                    }
                }
                cityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        };


        private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener citiesListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int city_id = Integer.parseInt(citiesIdList.get(position));
                Log.i("your_city_id", String.valueOf(city_id));

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        };

    }
```

Comment: I have used this projec https://github.com/joancolmenerodev/ProvinceAndCity2SpinnerFromJson

Comment: @alireza sorry for delay.  check now