# How to pass data to spinner

Tags: kotlin, android-spinner, serializable

I have:

`data class User( var name: String, var category: String) : Serializable`

and a spinner:

```
val categoryList: List<Category> = ArrayList()

categoryList.add(Category("beginner", 0xFFFFFFFF.toInt()))
categoryList.add(Category("intermediate", 0xFFE57373.toInt()))
categoryList.add(Category("advanced", 0xFFFFF176.toInt()))
```

For save data I do this:

```
editTextName.text.toString(),
spinner.selectedItem.toString()
```

Now I want to do the same from the other way:

```
editTextname.setText(user.name)
spinner. ???????  (user.category)
```

I don't know what to put here `???????`

So now I found this:

```
spinner.setSelection(user.category)
```

But `setSelection()` required a `Int` and I need a `String`

Maybe someone have an idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android : Fill Spinner From Java Code Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920754/android-fill-spinner-from-java-code-programmatically)

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072576/set-selected-item-of-spinner-programmatically

Comment: Thanks. It was very helpful but in my case something else is missing to pass :
spinner.setSelection(user.category)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to my problem.

```
var position = 0

for (item in categoryList) {
    if (item.category == user.category){
       position = categoryList.indexOf(item)
    }
}
```

So after you can do : `spinner.setSelection(position)`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should pass to `setSelection` position of user.category in your spinner adapter. I don't know how your spinner adapter looks like, but I suppose that this should do the job

Firstly change

```
val categoryList: List<Category> = ArrayList()
```

into

```
val categoryList: ArrayList<Category> = ArrayList()
```

then use

```
val category = categoryList.filter { category -> category.FIRST_PROPERTY == user.category}
spinner.setSelection(categoryList.indexOf(category))
```

Don't forget to replace `FIRST_PROPERTY` with name of yours property of Category class.

**Alternatively, you can use this method:**

```
private fun selectValue(spinner: Spinner, value: Any) {
    for (i in 0 until spinner.count) {
        if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i) == value) {
            spinner.setSelection(i)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but finally I found a solution before try yours.